# Theorem default names

Tags: theorems, amsthm, newtheorem

I am trying to produce the following effect:

```
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}
```

creates

> 1.2 **Theorem.**

and

```
\begin{theorem}[Uniform Boundedness Principle]
\end{theorem}
```

creates

> 1.2 **Uniform Boundedness Principle.**

I have tried using a `\IfValueTF` but it does not produce the desired result:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xstring}

% Theorem styles
\newtheoremstyle{testtheorem}
  {}
  {}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  { }
  {\thmnumber{#2}\IfValueTF{#3}{\thmname{ #1}}{\thmnote{ (#3)}}}

\theoremstyle{testtheorem}
\newtheorem{ttheorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{ttheorem}
\end{ttheorem}
\begin{ttheorem}[Test]
\end{ttheorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is fine but the problem is that the [amsthm](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package does not use the syntax from [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse). If no optional argument is given to a theorem environment then `#3` is set to `\relax` rather than `-NoValue-`, so rather than using `\IfValueTF` you need to test for `\relax`.

Changing your MWE to do this it becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Theorem styles
\newtheoremstyle{testtheorem}
  {}
  {}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  { }
  {\thmnumber{#2}\ifx#3\relax\relax\thmname{ #1}\else\thmnote{ #3}\fi}

\theoremstyle{testtheorem}
\newtheorem{ttheorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{ttheorem}
\end{ttheorem}
\begin{ttheorem}[Test]
\end{ttheorem}

\end{document}
```

and you obtain the desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `amsthm` package uses `\@ifempty` for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% Theorem styles
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{testtheorem}
  {}
  {}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  { }
  {\thmnumber{#2}\@ifempty{#3}{\thmname{ #1}}{\thmnote{ (#3)}}}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{testtheorem}
\newtheorem{ttheorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{ttheorem}
\end{ttheorem}
\begin{ttheorem}[Test]
\end{ttheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]